# What Extension/Plugin do you use/need?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

Some might need it, some might not. 
All those extra feature help noobs to gurus not only sometimes become a better programmer but also help them make their **life easier**.

One of the recent questions I found, was about the new `dynamic` variable introduced with the framework 4. Problem was it did not have highlighting nor intellisense. This was easily resolved with Resharper.

### *My question is what kind of Extensions/Plugins do you have or must die for ? *

*Add some bullet features and information pls so no one has to search*

And if possible not limited to Visual Studio as we all program in many different languages.

Visual Studio:

- [Visual Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306972/what-extension-plugin-do-you-use-need/5306996#5306996) by [0xc0deface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126163/0xc0deface)
- [RockScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306972/what-extension-plugin-do-you-use-need/5306996#5306996) by [0xc0deface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126163/0xc0deface)
- [Resharper for Visual Studio](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) :
  Highlighter, Intellisense and so much
  more
- [JustCode for Visual Studio](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx) :
  Highlighter, Intellisense

  Wonder: if we can make a faq about
  all the Extensions/Plugins available
  to us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your favorite visual studio plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74800/what-is-your-favorite-visual-studio-plugin)

Comment: @tvanfosson, was looking for such post, didn't see it till now.
But would still really like for all known ide's not only visual studio a mybe a bit more information on the extensions would be nice. If needed to do delete.

Comment: A comprehensive list of plug-ins for *all known IDEs* would be a truly massive undertaking, and certainly not one well-suited for a Q&A site like this one. Sorry, but that's clearly off-topic. If you have a *specific* question (like, what plug-in can I use for this particular IDE to achieve this specific task), that would be more on-topic and less likely to be closed.

Comment: Alright, sorry still new at this stackoverflow thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) and [Rockscroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) are what I use.

Rockscroll is free and is the best scroll bar implementation i've ever seen. It replaces the default VS scroll bar with an image of the file you are browsing that makes navigation a breeze. Also if you double click a variable or some other text it will highlight all occurances of it on the page in red on the scroll bar.

[image: Rockscroll]

Visual assist has far too many features to mention here, but [here](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/default.asp) is a link to their feature page. I will however mention some of its shortcuts that I believe add a lot to VS and that I use for code navigation daily without fail:

- Alt + Shift + O - open file in solution. It lets you type a few letters from the name of the file you want to open (enough to disambiguate) and hit enter, saving you from navigating in the solution explorer.
- Alt + M - Drops open a list of all functions in the current file, you can then type a few letters to disambiguate the function name you want and hit enter to be taken straight to it.
- Alt + Shift + S - Find symbol in solution. Like a powerful find all references for whatever you are searching for, including function names.
- Alt + O - switch between same named .h and .cpp files. I don't think i could live without this one, and am quite surprised that it VS doesn't have this out of the box.

It also costs $249 ($49 for students) but IMO is well worth it. I have been using it for 3 years and feel like the IDE is broken without it.

Comment: Wow, do you really use a font that big? Or is that a screenshot ripped from the RockScroll page?

Comment: Hahaha, yeah thats a screen shot from the RockScroll page.